# How to use two sliding drawer in android

Tags: android, slidingdrawer

When i made two sliding Drawer Onw Drawer is functional but other is not 
What i have done is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:background="#FCFCFC" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5px">
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_gravity="left" >
        <SlidingDrawer     android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="wrap_content"   android:id="@+id/SlidingDrawer" android:handle="@+id/slideHandleButton" android:content="@+id/contentLayout" android:padding="10dip" android:layout_height="60dip">
            <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/slideHandleButton" android:background="@drawable/projectmain"></Button>
                <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/contentLayout" android:orientation="horizontal" android:gravity="center" android:padding="10dip" android:background="@drawable/selector" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <TextView android:background="@drawable/selector" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textColor="#FFFFFF" android:textStyle="bold" android:textSize="16sp" android:text="Unlock" android:gravity="center" />
                </LinearLayout>
        </SlidingDrawer>
    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:background="#FCFCFC"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5px">
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_gravity="left" >
        <SlidingDrawer     android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="wrap_content"   android:id="@+id/SlidingDrawer1" android:handle="@+id/slideHandleButton1" android:content="@+id/contentLayout" android:padding="10dip" android:layout_height="60dip">
            <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/slideHandleButton1" android:background="@drawable/propertymain"></Button>
                <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/contentLayout" android:orientation="horizontal" android:gravity="center" android:padding="10dip" android:background="@drawable/selector" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <TextView android:background="@drawable/selector" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textColor="#FFFFFF" android:textStyle="bold" android:textSize="16sp" android:text="Unlock" android:gravity="center" />
                </LinearLayout>
        </SlidingDrawer>
    </LinearLayout>
```

What i have done on Java in is

I have  opened both  the drawer 
 like

setContentView(R.layout.main);

```
            slideHandleButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.slideHandleButton);
             slidingDrawer = (SlidingDrawer) findViewById(R.id.SlidingDrawer);
                slideHandleButton1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.slideHandleButton);
                 slidingDrawer1 = (SlidingDrawer) findViewById(R.id.SlidingDrawer);


                   slidingDrawer.setOnDrawerOpenListener(new OnDrawerOpenListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onDrawerOpened() {
                        Intent intent=new Intent(CurrentActivity.this,New Activity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                    });

                    slidingDrawer.setOnDrawerCloseListener(new OnDrawerCloseListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onDrawerClosed() {
                    }
                    });



                    slidingDrawer1.setOnDrawerOpenListener(new OnDrawerOpenListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onDrawerOpened() {
                            Intent intent=new Intent(CurrentActivity.this,NewActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                        });

                    slidingDrawer1.setOnDrawerCloseListener(new OnDrawerCloseListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onDrawerClosed() {
                        }
                        });
```

But Sliding Drawer 2nd is not working  Please Help 
Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this

```
slidingDrawer1 = (SlidingDrawer) findViewById(R.id.SlidingDrawer);
```

to

```
 slidingDrawer1 = (SlidingDrawer) findViewById(R.id.SlidingDrawer1);
```

Looks like you have provided the same id to both the elements.

Comment: I got to tell you this. Your xml looks like a mess. Why don't you format it.

Comment: Looks Like  i m FOOL what a silly mistake nayways Thanks MATE! i already  have formatted the code its bad down here i will edit it

Comment: Can i know 1 moe thing these image are on right of my layout how can i make my second image on left ?

Comment: I don't follow you. which Image are you talking abt?

Comment: The two button i mean to say Both the sliding drawer is aligned right i want second one on left

Comment: I am not sure. But try providing the gravity attributes to the Linear layout instead to sliding drawer elements.

Answer (score 1):

lOOK AT your java code you have used same id for both Sliding drawer